# Comparing two tab-delimiter files using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I obtained the text output file for my data sample which reports TE insertion sites in the genome. It looks like that:

```
sample  chr pos strand  family  order   support comment frequency
1   1   4254339 .   hAT|9   hAT R   -   0,954
1   1   34804000    .   Stowaway|41 Stowaway    R   -   1
1   1   12839440    .   Tourist|15  Tourist F   -   1
1   1   11521962    .   Tourist|10  Tourist R   -   1
1   1   28197852    .   Tourist|11  Tourist F   -   1
1   1   7367886 .   Stowaway|36 Stowaway    R   -   1
1   1   13130538    .   Stowaway|36 Stowaway    R   -   1
1   1   6177708 .   hAT|4   hAT F   -   1
1   1   3783728 .   hAT|20  hAT F   -   1
1   1   10332288    .   uc|12   uc  R   -   1
1   1   15780052    .   uc|5    uc  R   -   1
1   1   28309928    .   uc|5    uc  R   -   1
1   1   31010266    .   uc|33   uc  R   -   0,967
1   1   84155   .   uc|1    uc  F   -   1
1   1   3815830 .   uc|31   uc  R   -   0,879
1   1   66241   .   Mutator|4   Mutator F   -   1
1   1   15709187    .   Mutator|4   Mutator F   -   0,842
```

I want to compare it with the bed file representing TE sites for the reference genome. It looks like that:

```
chr start   end family
1   12005   12348   Tourist|7
1   4254339 4254340 hAT|9
1   66241   66528   Mutator|4
1   76762   76849   Stowaway|10
1   81966   82251   Stowaway|39
1   84155   84402   uc|1
1   84714   84841   uc|28
1   13130538    13130540    Stowaway|3
```

I want to check if TE insertions found in my sample occur in the reference, for example, if the first TE: hAT|9 in position 4254339 on chromosome 1 will be found in the bed file between the range defined by column 2 as the start and 3 as the end AND recognized as hAT|9 family according to column 4. I try to do it with pandas but I'm pretty confused. Thanks for the suggestions!

EDIT:
I slightly modified the input files view for easier understanding and parsing. Below is my code using pandas with two for loops (thanks @furas for suggesting).

```
import pandas as pd

ref_base = pd.read_csv('ref_test.bed', sep='\t')
te_output = pd.read_csv('srr_test1.txt', sep='\t')

result = []
for te in te_output.index:
    te_pos = te_output['pos'][te]
    te_family_sample = te_output['family'][te]
    for ref in ref_base.index:
        te_family_ref = ref_base['family'][ref]
        start = ref_base['start'][ref]
        end = ref_base['end'][ref]
        if te_family_sample == te_family_ref and te_pos in range(start, end):
            # print(te_output["chr"][te], te_output["pos"][te], te_output["family"][te], te_output["support"][te],
            #      te_output["frequency"][te])
            result.append(str(te_output["chr"][te]) + '\t' + str(te_output["pos"][te]) + '\t' + te_output["family"][te]
                          + '\t' + te_output["support"][te] + '\t' + str(te_output["frequency"][te]))
print(result)

resultFile = open("result.txt", 'w')

# write data to file
for r in result:
    resultFile.write(r + '\n')
resultFile.close()
```

There is my expected result:

```
1   4254339 hAT|9   R   0,954
1   84155   uc|1    F   1
1   66241   Mutator|4   F   1
```

I write it in the easy way as I could but I would like to find more efficient solution. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe do it with normal two `for`-loops.

Comment: Hi could you post the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()` for both your data and bed file, and also show what the expected result should look like?